# ActiveX Flash-Player can't access web-content?

Tags: windows, flash, security, com, console-application

I have a ActiveX control hosting a flash-player which is in turn running a flash file trying to access data from a web-address.

In an old *Windows Application* version of my application everything works fine and the flash file is able to access the web-content.

However, in a newer *Console Appliction* version of the application it can no longer access the web-content.

Any ideas what might be causing this? Is there some kind of difference between a Windows Application and a Console application in terms of security/permissions that might affect an ActiveX hosted flash-player?

I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - how did you manage to get an ActiveX into a console application? :) I think ax needs window handles and all such things...

Anyways, there are different kinds of sandboxes from the Flash player perspective, what you are seeing is the "local not trusted" kind. In order to "trust" the SWF that issues the request you would need to use [this page](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) to confirm that the location where SWF comes from can communicate to the internet.

Doing so may be a hindrance for the user, but if this is the case, you could write the trust files on your own. [Example](http://code.google.com/codesearch#cP6j1foN-l8/trunk/FD4/External/Plugins/ASCompletion/Commands/CreateTrustFile.cs)

Comment: It's a windowless ActiveX control :).